# Permission to uninstall shortcut on Android

Tags: android

I read somewhere else that it is

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

at the same time with a simple google I've also seen

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

What is the difference? The first seems to work but the second makes more sense and is in line of what I use for install.

To clarify, I'd like to know the proper permission setting in AndroidManifest to allow removal of a home screen shortcut from within the application.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: ?? what ? please make it clear

Comment: code block problem. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quickly Googling for `com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT`

I've seen it as an Intent action. So it's a BroadcastAction requesting the uninstallation.

The one `com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT` is the permission itself, probably to directly uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read on the [official documents page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), every permission contains `.permission.`, although the `UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT` permission was not listed. I would go under the assumption that it is the second of your suggestions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```